# How to access child tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have following tables: `Animal` and `ConcreteAnimal`. I am going database first approach if it makes any difference in this example. Suppose they are separate entities. Then I have 2 `DBSet(s)` generated, and can update separately either of the table. Things change once I set `ConcreteAnimal` as child of `Animal` in entity designer. Entity Set field of `ConcreteAnimal` in entity designer becomes disabled and is automatically populated with the value of entity set of its parent class `Animal`. `DBSet` for `ConcreteAnimal` is not longer generated in the context. This means that I can no longer access the second, child, table. How am I supposed to add `ConcreteAnimal`s to the database? Is it expected behavior? If yes, what is the logic behind it?

EDIT:
OK, I tried following code and it works.

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var concreteAnimal = new ConcreteAnimal
        {
            //setting properties here
            //both for Animal and specific to ConcreteAnimal
        };
    context.Animals.Add(concreteAnimal);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Magic happened, and both tables were populated with correct data. This is good. However, it just does not look logical to me why we have `DBSet` for base class only?

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using TPT Inheritance.

Common information are saved in the Animal table and specific information from a type in their own table.

You will find information you are looking in these articles:

- [Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)
- [Table per Type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)
- [Table per Concrete class (TPC)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)

**Edit**

> Why we have DBSet for base class only

It's actually a good question, I cannot give an exact answer but from my opinion this is not implemented by default because it's not necessary and would be very confusing.

Just imagine some very complex TPT scenario with a lot of inheritance, they would have one DbSet for every concrete class (which could be easily hundred of additional DbSet), then now you will have to ask to yourself, from which DbSet to do you have to retrieve, add or remove this concrete type.

You can easily add the code yourself once it's generated (in a partial class) and it's will work.

```
public DbSet<ConcreteAnimal> ConcreteAnimals { get; set; }
```

Comment: This actually does not answer my question. I know that I am using TPT. My question was specific - why we have DBSet for base type only?